# Why does my curser not focus on the focused element?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, dom

I have an editable main, in which when the user presses 'enter' a new paragraph element is appended to the child of this main element. The new paragraph element is then focused. However, the cursor doesn't automatically shift to the end of the text, it disappears. Why is this?

```
let m=document.getElementById('textEdit');
    function buttonClick(e){
  if (e.keyCode=="13"){
    e.preventDefault();
    let p=document.createElement("p");
    m.appendChild(p);
    p.tabIndex="-1";
    p.contentEditable='true';
    p.textContent="p";
    p.focus();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after `p.focus`:

```
 document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);
 document.getSelection().collapseToEnd();
```

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-glade-qsjlo